# TFS working with IBuildController in C#

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to trigger a build from C# 
In the build I need to change the default BuildController. My code look like this:

```
IBuildRequest buildRequest = BuildDefinition.CreateBuildRequest();
if(changebuildcontroller)
{
    buildRequest.DropLocation = @"\\zzz.Domain.com\yyy$\TFS\Drop";
    buildRequest.BuildController =  **???**;
}
...
var queuedBuild = buildServer.QueueBuild(buildRequest);
```

Questions:

1. I would like to know how to find a list of buildcontrollers.
2. Any advice about how to understand the TFS object model will be appreciated. I looked at MSDN articles like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildcontroller.aspx), but I do not see how it should help me. I used Google to find implementations of other objects in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client namespace.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to trigger a build from an application?

Comment: Because I need to meet a business requirement ;) Builds need to be triggered by a scheduler on another platform. I need to handle several other assignments while triggering multiple builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped looking at another assignment for a while :)

If anyone else run into the same problem Use the Ibuildserver object to get a list of IBuildController

```
buildServer = (IBuildServer)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
IBuildController[] buildserverlist = buildServer.QueryBuildControllers();
```